# Cascading for Impatient TFIDF example freezing

Tags: hadoop, cascading

I'm trying to work with Cascading to create and execute complex data processing workflows on a local Hadoop cluster.

I wish to create a TFIDF vector so I can apply Machine Learning algorithms such as NaiveBayes on it using the Apache Spark framework.

The problem is that after I create the jar and I launch it using the following commands the program freezes. [Here](https://gist.github.com/eliasah/5e5a5a9f16f625a22c9d) is the log file.

You can find the sources [here](https://github.com/Cascading/Impatient). The related source code is in part6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The nodes of the cluster were unhealthy but the log doesn't show that and cascading freezes as it's task has been UNASSIGNED.

[image]

So to solve the problem you have to correct the nodes health in my case I just had to correct hadoop-yarn containers directory and also it's local namenode directory.

You might run into other errors, So I suggest that you check your hadoop log files and the WebUI admin for Hadoop Nodes.